# onClick doesn't work on first click for MaterialUI FormControl API TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my React app, I am using a MaterialUI Form Control API TextField. In the Select tag, I am firing a method onClick, but it does fire only after first click. I don't have any hidden CSS applied to these tags. Here is the following snippet:

```
                    <FormControl style={{ width: '12em', marginTop: '1em' }} variant="outlined">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">Select Template</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            native
                            label="Select-Template"
                            onClick={this.GetTemplates}

                        >
                            {templates.length &&
                                templates.map(x => (
                                    <option
                                        key={x.template_id}
                                        value={JSON.stringify(x.template_content)}
                                        style={{ border: 'solid' }}>
                                        {x.template_name}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
```

**The function:**

```
GetTemplates = e => {
    XRayApi.getTemplates(this.getTemplatesApiResponse);
};
```

I cannot find out the reason at all. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onChange={this.GetTemplates}` in your code to get it working. As per the [official API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) of material-ui>select, onClick is not available. Now, your code will become

```
<FormControl style={{ width: '12em', marginTop: '1em' }} variant="outlined">
  <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">Select Template</InputLabel>
  <Select
  native
  label="Select-Template"
  onChange={this.GetTemplates}>
        {templates.length &&
            templates.map(x => (
                <option
                    key={x.template_id}
                    value={JSON.stringify(x.template_content)}
                    style={{ border: 'solid' }}>
                    {x.template_name}
                </option>
            ))}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: I was using onChange and onClick under the same tag. Resolved it by combining both of them into onChange.

Answer (score 1):

Try onChange instead of onClick in Select.

```js
<Select
  native
  label="Select-Template"
  onChange={this.GetTemplates}
>
```